# PayPal email status verification

Tags: php, authentication, curl, paypal

I was looking for a way to check if a number of emails are PayPal verified or not other than the API method which seemed way too complicated for a noob like me and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840658/how-safe-is-a-curl-function-from-being-sniffed) script which uses `https://www.paypal.com/us/verified/pal=` to verify email addresses.

but I just don't seem to get it to work I always get Login failed. Did PayPal change the login? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The script you linked is wrong, and is meant for users browsing the PayPal website: *"You must log in before you access this page."*, so **don't consider it**.

Calling cURL with sensitive data is also not safe and exposes you to sniffing by someone else: you need to use something which has encryption built-in.

I suggest that you use the official API from PayPal: you'll need to work a little bit, but it's the best method, supported directly from the company and you'll be sure it will always work. You're working in a sensitive environment like on-line payments, so this is very important.

If you have any problem implementing the API, ask here for help ;)